# How can I make qmake work if it's run in a directory with spaces?

Tags: build, directory, space, qmake

I'm in the directory `/Users/csaftoiu/VirtualBox VMs/shared/`

The last line of my `.pro` file is `system($$QMAKE_LRELEASE -silent $$_PRO_FILE_)`

The output of `qmake` is:

```
release error: Cannot open /Users/csaftoiu/VirtualBox: No such file or directory
```

None of these worked:

```
system($$QMAKE_LRELEASE -silent '$$_PRO_FILE_')
system($$QMAKE_LRELEASE -silent "$$_PRO_FILE_")
system($$QMAKE_LRELEASE -silent ''$$_PRO_FILE_'')
system($$QMAKE_LRELEASE -silent ""$$_PRO_FILE_"")
system($$QMAKE_LRELEASE -silent $$quote($$_PRO_FILE_))
system($$QMAKE_LRELEASE -silent $$quote('$$_PRO_FILE_'))
system($$QMAKE_LRELEASE -silent $$quote("$$_PRO_FILE_"))
system($$QMAKE_LRELEASE -silent $$quote(''$$_PRO_FILE_''))
system($$QMAKE_LRELEASE -silent $$quote(""$$_PRO_FILE_""))
system($$QMAKE_LRELEASE -silent `printf %q $$_PRO_FILE_`)
system($$QMAKE_LRELEASE -silent `printf %q '$$_PRO_FILE_'`)
system($$QMAKE_LRELEASE -silent `printf %q "$$_PRO_FILE_"`)
system($$QMAKE_LRELEASE -silent `printf %q ''$$_PRO_FILE_''`)
system($$QMAKE_LRELEASE -silent `printf %q ""$$_PRO_FILE_""`)
```

What on earth am I to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not, any and all of these do work:

```
system($$QMAKE_LRELEASE -silent \'$$_PRO_FILE_\')
system($$QMAKE_LRELEASE -silent \"$$_PRO_FILE_\")
system($$QMAKE_LRELEASE -silent "'$$_PRO_FILE_'")
system($$QMAKE_LRELEASE -silent '"$$_PRO_FILE_"')
```